# C^1 function twice differentiable only at origin?

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Is there a $C^1$ function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f$ is twice differentiable only at origin? Can this phenomena occur in higher dimension?

N.B I constructed a $C^1$ function that is twice differentiable nowhere but could not manipulate for one point. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could integrate a continuous function that is only differentiable at the origin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $h(x)$ be a continuous, nowhere differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$. Then $g(x)=x^2h(x)$ is continuous, and is differentiable only at $x=0$.

Therefore if we define $f(x)=\int_0^xg(t)\;dt$, then $f^{\prime}(x)=g(x)$ by the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, so $f$ is $C^1$ and is twice differentiable only at $x=0$.

Comment: example of such $h$ seems to be very advanced. I found one in wiki weierstrass function. btw does this construction work in higher dimensions?

Comment: The Weierstrass function is fairly complicated, but Rudin's *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* has a somewhat slicker example. I haven't thought about higher dimensions.

Comment: I am not familiar with the Rudin text. But the projection of the classic construction of the  Peano space filling curve $g:[0,1]\to [0,1]^2$ onto its first co-ordinate yields a continuous $ f:[0,1]\to [0,1]$ (which can be extended periodically to domain $\mathbb R$) such that when $j,n \in \mathbb N$ with $j\leq 4^n$  then $f([(j-1)4^{-n},j4^{-n}]) =$ $[(k-1)2^{-n},k2^{-n}]$  for some $k\in \mathbb N$ with $k\leq 2^{-n}.$  From this it is not hard to show that $f $ is nowhere differentiable.

Comment: In higher dimensions we can take such an $h$ that also satisfies $h(x)=h(-x)$ for all $x\in  \mathbb R.$ And for $v\in \mathbb R^n$  let $f(v)=\int_0^{\|v\|} x^2h(x)dx$ if you want $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$, OR $f(v)=v\cdot \int_0^{\|v\|}x^2h(x)dx$ if you want $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n.$

Comment: Instead of $g(x)=x^2h(x)$ we could also take $g(x)=x(h(x)-h(0).$.......+1